# How can I get a list of versions of jQuery using the Nuget console?

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to figure out a workaround for an issue I have with jQuery 2.0 being the version Nuget wants to update to via the GUI ([Can I keep Nuget on the jQuery 1.9.x/1.x path (instead of upgrading to 2.x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16125828/11912)).

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635453/11912) to another question it appears that I should be able to use the Nuget console to get all versions of jQuery:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter 'jQuery' -AllVersions
```

Then I should be able to pick the version I want and update it:

```
Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
```

or

```
Update-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1
```

Unfortunately, while updating works perfectly, trying to get a list of jQuery versions ends up grabbing numerous projects that merely refer to or contain jQuery in their title.

I suppose I could use `Open-PackagePage`, but that seems klunky.

However, I don't see any parameters that suggest I can filter by Id in [the official docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#Get-Package).

Is there a way to restrict the Nuget console to search only by project Id? Or is there some other way I can get a listing of versions of jQuery using the Nuget console? I've tried quotes around my jQuery filter (`-filter 'jQuery'`) but that didn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: Looks like there is no `-Id` parameter available for `Get-Package` (like there is for `Install-Package` and others), and I can see this being useful. I'd suggest submitting an issue on the NuGet issue tracker: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type `Install-Package JQuery -Version` then <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This displays a list of all available versions for that package.

The problem with `Get-Package` and its `-Filter` option is that it does a search of both `ID` and `Description` fields. I agree that it would be very useful if there was an `-ID` option or similar.

Comment: This solution doesn't always work.  As of today, if I type type above command, the latest version shows as 1.10.2 not 1.11.2.  But if I type 1.11.2 the command works, so clearly the version exists.

Comment: @MobyDisk Make sure your Package Source is set to nuget.org and not the Microsoft Curated Packages feed. (There's a drop-down in the Package Manager Console window.) At the time of writing, the nuget feed should be https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/