# javascript error when launching fresh new MVC4 application in IE10

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the following error when launching my MVC4 application. Can some one shine some light? Nothing has been added yet by me. It was working fine yesterday. I tried creating a fresh new MVC4 application and I still get the error. It pops when I launch it. The initial page does not even appear yet. It's happening only with IE10. Works fine in other browsers.

[image: Runtime error when launching MVC4 application]

Comment: jQuery 1.7.2 is pretty out of date. Although this might not solve your problem, update your version of jQuery using the Nuget package manager. If you need to support older versions of IE, don't update to the 2.x branch but instead aim for 1.10.x... [See here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125828/can-i-keep-nuget-on-the-jquery-1-9-x-1-x-path-instead-of-upgrading-to-2-x)

Comment: This is unusual, Visual Studio shouldn't be debugging JavaScript files unless... IE is attached to the debugging. Have you tried launching with another browser such as Chrome?

Comment: It works fine with the other browsers. I'm running IE10.